# install ext-zmq for ratchet push integration

Tags: php, zeromq

I'm trying to install [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) for the push integration on [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/push), I have successfully integrated Ratchet unto my Laravel 5 app. I downloaded and install the [zeroMQ software](http://ttp://www.zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software) and in the [PHP binding instruction page](http://zeromq.org/bindings%3Aphp), I followed the set up instruction for windows section since I'm on windows 10

> Download the latest snapshot from http://snapshot.zero.mq/
>
> Copy libzmq.dll into your php directory (e.g.
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8)
>
> Copy the appropriate version of php_zmq.dll to your php extension
>   directory (e.g. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext)
>
> Add the following line to your php.ini:
>
> extension=php_zmq.dll

since http://snapshot.zero.mq/ is a broken link so I look around the internet for other source and I found [this link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/) and downloaded the **php_zmq-1.1.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip** one. I copy the libzmq.dll to **C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12** as instructed as well as the **php_zmq.dll** to **C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext** and then I add

> extension=php_zmq.dll

to my php ini and restarted my wamp server but it throws me this warning,

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_zmq.dll' - The specified module
>   could not be found

Any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the correct file from here https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq that match unto my php version and then restart my computer and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Get the version from here:
https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.2/windows

In my case, the correct version that works was 1.1.2